# Transfer coordinates from GPS unit to web server without a live machine

Tags: gps, tracking, gpsd

I want to send GPS coordinates from a GPS unit to server with 2 minutes interval. As for as my knowledge is concerned GPS units can not send data directly to a web service. How can I receive the data (using SMS or IP:Port method) at server end with the most cost effective way. I can not own a live server. 
Will web server work for me? Is there any free service available for this?

Please Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Where are the GPS coordinates coming from?

Comment: GPS unit installed in a vehicle.

Comment: How does the GPS unit send the data?

Comment: What connections does the GPS unit have? Do it have an NMEA port? Is this a hardware question? (How would you send using SMS? Is there a cellphone somewhere in the picture?)

Comment: It can send data using SMS or to an IP. Yes got a NMEA port. No cell phone is the picture yet.

Comment: What protocol does it use to send to an IP?

Comment: So you need a server that can accept whatever format the GPS uses to send data to an IP. So, that brings us to Juhana's question -- what format is that? If it's an HTTP POST, then a web server can take it.

Comment: Sorry I am new to GPS kind of thing, it asks for an IP and port.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you mean to say that there are GPS devices that can accept HTTP POST address and they directly post data to it? If GPS device can accept HTTP addresses then it means that It can post data to a web service. What I would do is just extract the incoming strings and dump them in DB.

Comment: @OmegaCancer: Some do an HTTP POST, some don't. The trick is to make a server somewhere that can accept whatever it does. (If it just asks for IP and port, it's probably not an HTTP POST, but who knows.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz IP:Port scheme throws the data to a live machine on a specific port, you need a daemon or a service on that machine that is constantly listening on that port, But in my case I can not own a live machine, That was my question that how can I do it without having a live server.

Comment: @OmegaCancer: Right, in what format though? It could be an HTTP POST, it could be an NMEA stream over TCP. We can't possibly know.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz format is not a issue. The issue is to get hands on the data because a web service can not access the system port. To access port you need to have access on machine so that you can install a daemon service.

Comment: @OmegaCancer: You can't get your hands on the data without knowing the format. If it's an HTTP POST, then you get your hands on the data one way. If it's NMEA over TCP, you get your hands on the data a completely different way. Maybe I just totally don't understand your question. (Every web server is constantly listening on a port for HTTP requests -- that's what makes it a web server.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks very much for bearing me. I think what I require is a bit more homework.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz While my search I came accross this: [link]http://forums.asp.net/t/1843966.aspx/1?How+to+Read+GPS+data+from+gps+device+in+context+of+ASP+NET (Please read the last reply of k.panchal that says "GPS cant sent data directly to the web server, for this you have to bridge your data through the medium of live server.")and I went to local GPS shop but he was totally blank about HTTP POST and NMEA so can you name few manufacturers along with models that supports HTTP POST format that would make thing more clear to me please. Thanks